I need to use Thevenin's theorem to find I2
In this example, they ask the value of \$I_2\$. My teacher teached to us the basics of Thevenin's theorem but I really don't know how I would solve a complex problem like this. I tried online resources but nothing is working for me.
I believe I was able to solve for \$I_A\$ and \$V_A\$ by short circuiting the place where the 7 Ω resistor is. I got \$I_A=0.8A\$ and \$V_A=8.1V\$ and the corresponding currents.


What work have you done already and where did you get stuck?

@ZacharyBrown please edit your question ... add the explanation there, it does not belong in a comment

Zachary, this kind of problem is usually handled with either nodal or mesh analysis, especially so due to the dependent sources. Have you experience there?

no i have 0 experience with those

@ZacharyBrown Then I think you need to talk more about what lessons you have absorbed. I know that you said you "shorted" the 7 Ohm resistor. But that doesn't seem right to me. And it doesn't tell me what you are being taught here. So I'd need more information before considering writing anything. Perhaps show what work you did?

6 Nodes for KCL at least 5 loops for KVL. Choose what is sufficient to get N equations and N unknowns to find i2

@D.A.S. Zachary says he doesn't know KCL (nodal) or KVL (mesh). If I'm reading the comment, correctly.

@ZacharyBrown Hmmm....usually you learn Thevenin after nodal and mesh.  Anyway, I can't really help you with the approach, but here is what the answers should be (assuming I set up the simulation correctly) so you at least know what you're aiming for.  https://i.sstatic.net/9nWIn56K.png

None of the comments or the answer give any way to apply Thevenin's theorem.  The only part of the circuit that could be converted is the 12V source and the 6 and 7 ohm resistors, and that conversion isn't much help. So, OP's question is indirectly answered - no one has a clue. I don't either.  I hope he can post what he finds out after his homework is graded.

I have more to say, if interedted. You'd have to open a chat room.
